LaunchScreen black then white before app starts (Quasar app with capacitor)
Novice app developer. I built an iOS app with Quasar using capacitor. The splashscreen/launchscreen was prepared with Icon Genie. When the app is launched in the simulator, the screen is black then turns white before the app is ready for use. I do not see a launchscreen.
I have reviewed many resources online and I can't find something that looks wrong.
I'm just not sure where to look to start spotting an answer.
quasar.config.js
capacitor: {
  hideSplashscreen: false,
}

I can't install the capacitor/splashscreen plugin because I have a dev dependency conflict with @revenuecat/capacitor
Here is info.plist

Launchscreen storyboard appears correct. The image size is 40kb.

